# Where can I find city/town location data for location-based searching?

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, geocoding

I need to implement find entries with x miles of town function, so I have a town box with autosuggest attached. Currently I'm using Google's Geocoding API to get the data for the autosuggest results, but we obviously can't tune or alter this data and it doesn't always come up with sensible suggestions (even with a country hint). Are there any other sources of town/city location data? I've tried to see if perhaps an export was available from OpenStreetMap or something but I can only find map tiles or vector map data and not POI data for town/city names and locations.

Any suggestions appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Have you searched for Google Place API? I think its a good option for location based searching. Another one is Foursquare API. Rest of the things you can find from the documents..
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/
https://developer.foursquare.com/

Hope this may help you.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Geonames.org has a downloadable list of cities and even postal codes for many countries around the world along with their corresponding lat/lon point.  It's under the Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 License which means that you can use it commercially, but you have to give attribution, among other things.

While having a downloadable list may mean more work on your end in terms of implementing all of the facets of the search algorithm, the silver lining is that you don't couple yourself to the uptime/availability of a 3rd-party web service.

The only other part that's missing is the distance-calculation formula.  You can use the [greater-circle distance formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Great-circle_distance) to compute distance.

I've done this myself a number of times.  The first time you write the code, it takes a little bit to wrap your head around everything, but once you do it's a piece of cake thereafter.

I should probably mention that I'm the founder of [SmartyStreets](http://www.smartystreets.com).  We do street-based address verification and not only can we tell you if an address is good or not (which helps in a significant number of ways), but we can also give you the lat/lon coordinate for a given street address which can then be plugged in to the above solution to determine proximity to nearby places.

Comment: Thanks - I will look into geonames. At the mo it almost seems to have too many results but perhaps I can filter it by something. Unfortunately I'm not sure there's anything in the data I can filter it by to get rid of all the villages/hamlets etc both in the UK or overseas.

Comment: Have you tried narrowing it down based upon postal code? (http://download.geonames.org/export/zip/)

Comment: @JonathanOliver, I am looking for the list of Restaurants near by the User's current location. Specifically for India. Can you tell me that does your service will provide me that data? If yes then will it be free or paid??

Comment: @Scorpion, sorry, we don't India.  Our service is both free and paid.

Answer (score 2):

I would say you also have two other options to get the functionality you require.

Firstly, you can use a kludge to focus the results to more meaningful ones (although I would not strongly recommend this method it may suffice for your needs.)

Before your initial query to Google's Geocoding API to get the data for the autosuggest results, firstly determine the country the town is in. Then you can use the country string as a suffix to the Geocoding query.

Something like:

```
  var country = 'UK'; // from initial query, reverse geocode, etc.
  geocoder.geocode({
          'address': address + ', ' + country
       },
```

See the answer in this question for an example.
[Google's Geocoder returns wrong country, ignoring the region hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647086/googles-geocoder-returns-wrong-country-ignoring-the-region-hint/2647165#comment11972365_2647165)

Secondly, the premise that you "obviously can't tune or alter this data" is flawed. You can certainly filter the results based on the country. Something like the following snippet shows how to drill down the results.

```
   geocoder.geocode({
      'address': address
   }, 
   function(results, status) {
      if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
         for(var i = 0, l = results.length; i < l; i++)  {
          for (var j = 0, l2 = results[i].address_components.length; j < l2; j++) {
              for (var k = 0, l3 = results[i].address_components[j].types.length; k < l3; k++) {
                 if(results[i].address_components[j].types[k]=="country") {
                    var country = results[i].address_components[j].long_name;
                    // do stuff based on the country
                    // add the result to your auto-suggest, etc...
                 }
              }
         }
      }
    });
   }
```

Finally, if you implemented a CGI wrapper to do the geocoding you could cache the results. This way your application would automatically build your database for you. This would save actually having to perform geocoding at all for known results. I think this is almost what you are hinting at in your question, and there is no reason you could not pre-populate your cache with known results if you did find a reliable source of data.

Take a look at this document that outlines various Geocoding Strategies using the Maps Api - it discusses things like caching, etc.
https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/geocodestrat

**EDIT**

You could use something like geoPlugin

http://www.geoplugin.com/webservices/php#php_class

Take a look at the nearby places features, this does exactly what you want.

http://www.geoplugin.com/webservices/extras

Comment: Thanks, but I do not know what country the city they are searching on is in as they're just typing in free text :(

Comment: If you don't know the country then any suggestion is surly sensible... Also, you state "even with a country hint" in the question - so  what country hint did you use if did not know the country?

Comment: I can't see any geoplugin service which does what I'm asking for in my question. It seems the service is for reverse geocoding but I have no need to do that.

Comment: @NickG - you are asking about implementing "find entries with x miles of town function" the geoplugin has this functionality - "www.geoplugin.net/extras/nearby.gp?lat=XXX&long=YYY&limit=10&radius=50"

Comment: Also, if you claim not to know the lat lng of the town, then any result is sensible. Also, do you know the country or not? Your question and subsequent comments contradict each other...

Comment: Sorry if I was unclear, but by "find entries" I meant find entries my database (hotels/conference venues etc) by a town the user has already selected - not that I was trying to find towns or cities within x miles of a lat/long.

Comment: ...hence my use of the word "town" later in the sentence. Sorry if that was not clear but thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://geohash.org/, this site working with many api's that you may want to use. See also the [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geohash) about the history of this site