# Get only country specific result using google geocode api

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, geocoding, google-geocoder

I am using google geocode api for fetching lat long using **postal code** of singapore

I have tried following to fetch data:

(1) http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=505468&sensor=false

(2) http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Singapore%20505468&sensor=false

(3) http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Singapore%20505468&sensor=false&region=sg

But it returns location from India

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=fr#RegionCodes

Any other way to get only country specific (Singapore) result.

I have tried following it returns correct result

http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Singapore%20133224&sensor=false

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google's Geocoder returns wrong country, ignoring the region hint](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647086/googles-geocoder-returns-wrong-country-ignoring-the-region-hint)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

To restrict results to a specific country use the component-filtering.

The url should be [`http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Singapore%20505468&sensor=false&components=country:SG`](http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Singapore%20505468&sensor=false&components=country:SG)

But that's not the issue here, the geocoder-result is wrong, because the result has the country set to `SG`, but the location is wrong(placed in india).

I'm afraid with the given address(it appears that the postcode doesn't exists), the only thing you can do is to report the wrong result to google.

Comment: Thanks for your help and I have found this solution if we pass `postal_code` with api request than we will get only specific postal code result. 
`http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=505468&components=country:SG|postal_code:505468&sensor=false`
                 
`http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=787878&components=country:SG|postal_code:787878&sensor=false`       
But I want that user can search by any address, street name or postal code so above solution will not work.

I will going to report about this to google.

Comment: multiple country is not supported components=country:us|components=country:pr is not working

Comment: how to set multiple countries in components while make a google api autocomplete call ?

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Raf&sensor=false&types=(regions)&key=YOUR_API_KEY&components=country:ESP|country:uk|country:us

Answer (score 31):

The correct way of doing this is by providing [componentRestrictions](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#GeocodingRequests)

For example:

```
var request = {
    address: address,
    componentRestrictions: {
        country: 'UK'
    }
}
geocoder.geocode(request, function(results, status){
    //...
});
```

Comment: Exact duplicate of [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2647086/googles-geocoder-returns-wrong-country-ignoring-the-region-hint/22081927#22081927), stop posting duplicate answers and there by not creating redundancy.

Comment: You both saw it was a duplicate question: the correct procedure is to close the question on that basis.

Comment: Saved my life! Thanks

Answer (score 11):

you can set single country or multiple countries

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Raf&sensor=false&types=(regions)&key=YOUR_API_KEY&components=country:ESP

or

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/autocomplete/json?input=Raf&sensor=false&types=(regions)&key=YOUR_API_KEY&components=country:ESP|country:uk|country:us

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It helps me a lot. I was searching for solution for multiple country

Comment: @SourabhSharma there is limit of maximum 5 country code

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use this approach 
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?components=country:US|postal_code:5037

remove the address and to the component pass the postal code and make sure if the address has a value let pass another value selected by the user with the postal code to validate your api or else without postal code passed it will leak to another address